# Filling and manipulating matrices using MathNet.Numerics

Tags: c#, matrix, linear-algebra, mathnet-numerics, numerics

I'm working on a code where I need to represent a small number of matrices (around 10) and do some operations with them (like get the inverse, transposed, etc). One of my co-workers recommended using the Math.Net Iridium library. The referred page said the project was Discontinued and merged with `MathNeh.Numerics`, found [here](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/).

I manage to install the package successfully. But now, I'm struggling to use the operations properly.

To sum up, what I am asking is: **how to put data into matrices and manipulate them using `MathNet.Numerics`?** For instance, how can I add values to a specific row x column y in a given matrix m1. Does it allow us to access a specific index?

One more thing to note, the matrices will always have the same number of columns and rows, but this number is known in run-time only.

I've tried to google for tutorials, found [this](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html) one, but I didn't get what I needed to know. Any help is appreciated.

--
*PS: the method I was using so far was creating Nested Lists to represent each matrix, and using for loops to populate it. I believe I would have a hard time when the time to transpose/invert/multiply would come.*

Comment: This is described shortly in the docs you linked. What is remaining unclear? http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Manipulating-Matrices-and-Vectors

Comment: @ChristophRüegg Would you believe me if I say I skipped that "Manipulating Matrices and Vectors" part? Well, I'll read it all over again, just to be sure. Thanks for taking your time to answer a terrible fail question.

Comment: No worries, but do let us know if you have suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the documentation linked in the question itself. http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Manipulating-Matrices-and-Vectors

The given example is:

```
var m = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(3,4,(i,j) => 10*i + j);
m[0,0]; // 0   (row 0, column 0)
m[2,0]; // 20 (row 2, column 0)
m[0,2]; // 2   (row 0, column 2)
m[0,2] = -1.0;
m[0,2]; // -1
```